# Touching one end of a battery

Tags: electricity, voltage

What happens when I touch one end of a battery? Is there any flow of charge from the battery to my body?

I know that connecting a battery to both ends of capacitor causes the charge from one plate to move to the other plate, while no charge is taken from the battery itself. If we used a different voltage source than a battery, would it be the same? Or is it because of chemical reactions happening in the battery?

Comment: Your guess that there will be a current flow is correct. It's not just a theoretical problem but a real one. A lot of the problems related to static electricity stem from charge always spreading out over the largest possible area. A technical treatment would be using coefficients of potential (aka capactiance coefficients): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficients_of_potential

Answer (score 1):

These are in fact two questions. I'll do my best to give undestandable explanations to both.

The two poles of a battery are kept by it at a fixed voltage. This is equivalent to say that the conducting pin at one end of the battery can be regarded as a **source of electrons**, the one at the other end as a pit for them to be dragged towards. 
If you now think of the ground you are standing upon, that's connected with the whole of the Earth's crust, mostly conducting: thus an immense (for our purposes "infinitely extended") source AND pit of electrons at your disposal. From the point of view of what I wrote before, this means the ground has always a lower voltage that any positive voltage battery pin, and a higher voltage than any negative one. It is indeed always at 0 V.

You now see how the ends of a battery are not only at a different voltage between themselves, but that **each of them sure holds a voltage difference between itself and the floor**.
Wear anything other that insulating (e.g. rubber) shoes, and charge will be flowing throug your body down to the ground even if you are touching just one end of the battery.

For the purposes of circuit electronics, **a battery is usually regarded as just a voltage source**, meaning that you don't care about its inner workings. You just assume it has some way of producing "electromotive force" (of course by getting energy from an entirely different realm of Physics than that of ohmic electronic circuits).

Comment: My guess was that touching one end of the battery will cause the current to flow for a very short time. See this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132360/why-batteries-in-serial-dont-discharge-each-other It's basically the same as connecting negative end of battery A to positive end to battery B - they won't discharge.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you put your finger on the plus pole of a battery. The minus pole will allready have a small capacitance to all its surroundings including your body and the ground. If your feet are not insulated from the ground the charge on this small capacitance will be altered through a short flow of electrons until the voltage difference between its "plates" equal the battery voltage. If your feet are insulated then your feet can be considered to be one plate and the ground the other plate of a comparatively greater capacitor. But this is in series with the previous small capacitor so the current spike will be less than before and the capacitors will be charged to a voltage inversely proportional to their individual capacitance, the sum being the battery voltage.
One could say that the action of touching one pole effectively short-circuits the capacitance between the pole and your body resulting in a current flow for redistributing all the involved charges.